# What is absolute easiest way to print from a mobile browser to a thermal (bluetooth) printer?

Tags: android, printing, bluetooth, thermal-printer

I am not sure if this can be done, but here is what I am trying to do:

I want to be able to pull up data from our website, hit some type of print button on the site, which than makes a call to a paired bluetooth printer and prints the displayed data (in simple html). I understand that Android does not have have a print function built in, so how would you go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the printing part, there is printer discovery and selection, as well as print error detection and recovery to consider. Some of these may not be feasible to handle from a web page, and better handled by another app, either your custom app using the particular printer manufacturer’s SDKs and drivers, or an off the shelf app. For off the shelf app, you may want to checkout [centvia](http://www.centsoftware.com/centvia) for single-touch printing (similar to your print button reference) from a web page on Android or iOS.

Comment: centvia looks like exactly what I have in mind! Thank you so much! I was searching for hours (literally) trying to find a good solution. Going to play with this, thanks again!

Comment: Have you actually used centvia before?

Comment: I helped develop centvia and worked with developers to integrate centvia into their applications.

Answer (score 0):

> I understand that Android does not have have a print function built in

Android 4.4 and higher offers [printing](http://developer.android.com/training/printing/index.html).

> so how would you go about this?

I would start by finding a Web site, email address, or phone number of my Bluetooth printer manufacturer. Then, I would use those resources to see what Android support they may have. If they offer support for Android 4.4 printing, I would use that. If they do not, but they have their own Android API for printing, I would use that. If they do not have either of those, I would move on to another printer manufacturer.

It is certainly conceivable that you could cook up your own print-to-Bluetooth mechanism, but getting an already-supported printer should be less expensive.